# How to get the indicies from sort or member commands in MAXIMA

Tags: sorting, maxima

The sort or member functions in MAXIMA do not return the indicies of elements sorted or the index of element being searched for. Is there a sort function that returns indices? Thanks.

Sven

Answer (score 0):

There aren't built-in functions for those tasks, but I think you can write something fairly easily:

```
member_index (x, l) :=
 (sublist_indices (l, lambda ([y], x = y)),
  if %% = [] then false else first (%%));
```

This `member_index` function returns the index of the first instance of `x`. If you want indices for all instances, just remove the `if` expression and return `%%` instead.

```
ranks (l) :=
  block ([l1, l2],
         makelist ([l[i], i], i, length (l)), 
         l1 : sort (%%, lambda ([x, y], orderlessp (x, y))),
         l2 : makelist (0, length (l)),
         for i thru length (l) do l2[l1[i][2]] : i,
         l2);
```

This `ranks` function returns integer values when there are ties (i.e. same values). Sometimes it is preferable to return the average rank for ties; that take a little more code. There is a `ranks` function in share/amatrix/wilcoxon.mac which does average ties. You can load that function via `load(wilcoxon);`.